# Problems with PHP Soap Server caching response

Tags: php, caching, soap

I've successfully created a client and server soap object... but having real problems with what I think is caching on the server side. I'm disabling all caching on both client and server scripts with:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_ttl", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
```

But I seem to get exactly the same response from the server no matter what I do. I've changed the object names, changed the WSDL name and even appended a timestamp to the object names to make sure it's never the same each call. Then suddenly, after about 10 or 20 minutes or so it will update and I'll get a different response. I've checked phpinfo() and it says the caching ttl is a day long (globally), so I think it's definitely shorter than that.

Any ideas about killing off any kind of caching?

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the options to SOAP objects:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

$server = new SoapServer("some.wsdl", array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
```

If this does not help, try to clear the wsdl cache file. On linux, it's usually in /tmp folder and it's name starts with `wsdl-`. If clearing this file does not help, maybe some other cache is used? Is it just SoapServer or are some additional libs used?

Comment: Thanks $server = new SoapServer("some.wsdl", array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE)); worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and trying to set:

```
  new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE))
```

did nothing.

In the end, I located the /tmp folder the server used to cache the wsdl file and just delete it.  Fixed!

The /tmp folder was not in my virtual domain /tmp folder, but at the root of the server directory.